# Android - Convert iOS Swift function into java method

Tags: java, android, swift

I am trying to convert a Swift function into a Java method without result:

Swift

```
static func getFeed(feedsCount: (newsFeeds : [Int]) -> Void) {

       feedsCount(newsFeeds: [12, 13])
}
```

How could I convert this into Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
interface FeedCounter {
    void count(int... newFeeds);
}

static void getFeed(FeedCounter feedCounter) {
    feedCounter.count(12, 13);
}
```

Sample call:

```
getFeed(new FeedCounter() {
    @Override
    public void count(int... newFeeds) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

In Java 8 you'd be able to call it like this:

```
getFeed(newFeeds -> doSomething);
```